# How to install Terraform in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install terraform in Ubuntu desktop but I am getting error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/terraform: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"
```

The same steps working for cloud servers.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Steps to install terraform on Ubuntu / Ubuntu cloud server :

1. Install unzip

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unzip
   ```
2. Confirm the latest version number on the terraform website:

   ```
   https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
   ```
3. Download latest version of the terraform (substituting newer version number if needed)

   ```
   wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.0.7/terraform_1.0.7_linux_amd64.zip
   ```
4. Extract the downloaded file archive

   ```
   unzip terraform_1.0.7_linux_amd64.zip
   ```
5. Move the executable into a directory searched for executables

   ```
   sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin/
   ```
6. Run it

   ```
   terraform --version
   ```

Comment: The version number is outdated.

Comment: `sudo install terraform /usr/local/bin/` is more reliable, it ensures ownership and permissions are correct.

Comment: What does the `sudo install` actually add here? I'm asking this because I am getting "install: cannot stat 'terraform': No such file or directory" when trying to run it, and can't get it to work as intended. Feeling awkward about not using this command ever before...

Comment: Leave it , Just Move the files that all. and later check the version.

Comment: @matt you need to use `install` instead of` `mv`, otherwise if you call it after `mv` there will no terraform file in your current directory, and you will get an error.

Comment: If you require a specific version of terraform, you can find them all here: https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/

Answer (score 17):

If you’re running Ubuntu plus snap installed, just call:

```
sudo snap install terraform --classic
```

Comment: Something about the way snap installs the binary breaks integration with ssh-agent. terraform works fine if I install it with snap and then call the binary via its full path `/snap/terraform/216/bin/terraform apply`. But I just use `terraform apply` and let PATH find `/snap/bin/terraform`, the binary cannot use my ssh-agent.

Comment: note that snap is not always install the last version (currently it can install v0.11.11 while the last major version is v0.12.5

Answer (score 13):

What about using Terraform official deb repository, you can than install and update  Terraform using `apt`.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/install/apt.html#repository-configuration

Like this:

```
curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install terraform
```

Answer (score 4):

My one-liner to install the latest version:

```
sudo echo ; zcat <( CURRR_VER=$(curl -s https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform | jq -r -M '.current_version') ; curl -q "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${CURRR_VER#?}/terraform_${CURRR_VER#?}_linux_amd64.zip" ) | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/terraform > /dev/null ; sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/terraform
```

Using the line from https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9803#issuecomment-257903082

Answer (score 0):

This error occured when you try run 64 bit exec file on 32 bit system.
Check your system:

> uname -a

x86_64 or i686 mean 64 or 32 bit accordinary.

Comment: This answer is just generally true of software and not directly relevant to the question asked.

Comment: You are right, my bad =). This addition to the approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 3 different tools that can help you to install and use specific versions of Terraform (similar to nvm, pyenv, rbenv, rustup tools):

- `tfswitch`: https://github.com/warrensbox/terraform-switcher/
- `cloudposse/tfenv`: https://github.com/cloudposse/tfenv
- `tfutils/tfenv`: https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv/

I like the first one as it was made in golang and a `snap` package is available (but not currently in latest version https://github.com/warrensbox/terraform-switcher/issues/126).

The most popular is `tfutils/tfenv/` and that's the one that I'm using right now.

Answer (score 0):

I referred to [The Official Terraform Website](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli) to install **Terraform** for **Ubuntu** and **Debian**.

Ensure that your system is up to date, and you have the gnupg, software-properties-common, and curl packages installed. You will use these packages to verify HashiCorp's GPG signature, and install HashiCorp's Debian package repository:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gnupg software-properties-common curl
```

Add the HashiCorp GPG key:

```
curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the official HashiCorp Linux repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main"
```

Update to add the repository, and install the Terraform CLI:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install terraform
```

Check if **Terraform** is successfully installed:

```
terraform -v
```

Comment: I used this in a CI/CD pipeline to update Terraform. For some reason `terraform version` gives me the old version, not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -8):

```
sudo apt-get install terraform
```

then run the command `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

will help you to get the suitable version of the teraform into the simulated hardware that was fetched from the Ubuntu install or any of the Linux version installed into your system.

Comment: there isn't a terraform apt package....

Comment: This answer is wrong in multiple ways, it should be deleted.

Comment: Please it must be updated with the latest official terraform installation doc https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli